# Zend Framework 2 Override an existing Service?

Tags: service, zend-framework2

I am using a zf2 module called `GoalioRememberMe` and now I want to override its service by my customized service. Or if it is not possible, I want to override the Module.php with my config. Is it possible?

In the Application module. I wrote this line in module.config.php:
`'GoalioRememberMe\Service\RememberMe' => 'Application\Service\RememberMe'`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is exactly the reason it is recommended to name the service as the type of the object that is returned. The object `GoalioRememberMe\Service\RememberMe` is named `goaliorememberme_rememberme_service` in the service manager. You can check that [here](https://github.com/goalio/GoalioRememberMe/blob/master/src/GoalioRememberMe/Module.php#L30).

So the solution is simple, instead of this:

```
'GoalioRememberMe\Service\RememberMe' => 'Application\Service\RememberMe'
```

Write this

```
'goaliorememberme_rememberme_service' => 'Application\Service\RememberMe'
```

Comment: tnx. This is really what I want.

Comment: Here it is an error:  A service by the name or alias "goaliorememberme_rememberme_service" already exists and cannot be overridden; please use an alternate name...

Comment: I think this happens because Goalio sets the service in the `getServiceConfig()` method inside the module class. You try to override the service in the config file. If you put this in the service config method too, will this fix the issue? Otherwise, see this answer to override an existing service: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17814122/zf2-re-starting-service-manager-key

Comment: Slumiman Thanks very much. I followed your link and combined it with your post and post a new answer. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

As Jurian said, the service name is `goaliorememberme_rememberme_service` and it has been set in the `getServiceConfig()` method. So I wrote this code in the `Module.php` file in the Application Module:

```
$serviceManager->
            setAllowOverride(true)->
            setInvokableClass('goaliorememberme_rememberme_service', 'Application\Service\CustomRememberMe')->
            setAllowOverride(false);
```

And it replaced successfully with my customized service!
Thanks very much to Jurian for the big help!

Answer (score 0):

Actually the service manager first runs a method "canonicalizeName()" which "normalizes" the names as follows:

1. All _ / \ and - are stripped out
2. The key is made lowercase

Thus both "GoalioRememberMe\Service\RememberMe" and "goaliorememberme_rememberme_service" become "goalioremembermeremembermeservice" (i.e. they're both the same), thus the error message.

The quickest way to override an existing service is to create a *local.php or *global.php file in the /config/autoload folder.  (That folder is identified in config/application.config.php.)  Any override files in this folder are process *after* modules are loaded.  If you have duplicate service manager keys, the last one wins.